# How to put a condition in regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex like --

```
query = "(A((hh)|(hn)|(n))?)"
```

and an input `inp = "Ahhwps edAn"`. I want to extract all the matched pattern along with unmatched(remaining) but with preserving order of the input.
The output should look like -- `['Ahh', 'wps ed', 'An']` or `['Ahh', 'w', 'p', 's', ' ', 'e', 'd', 'An']`.
I had searched online but found nothing.
How can I do this?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Thanks a lot. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) method may output captured submatches in the resulting array.

Capturing groups are those constructs that are formed with a pair of unescaped parentheses. Your pattern abounds in redundant capturing groups, and `re.split`  will return all of them. You need to remove those unnecessary ones, and convert all capturing groups to non-capturing ones, and just keep the outer pair of parentheses to make the whole pattern a single capturing group.

Use

```
re.split(r'(A(?:hh|hn|n)?)', s)
```

Note that there may be an empty element in the output list. Just use `filter(None, result)`  to get rid of the empty values.

Comment: I observed empty strings and removed them. Thanks for suggesting `filter` method.

Answer (score 2):

The match objects' span() method is really useful for what you're after.

```
import re

pat = re.compile("(A((hh)|(hn)|(n))?)")
inp = "Ahhwps edAn"

result=[]
i=k=0
for m in re.finditer(pat,inp):
    j,k=m.span()
    if i<j:
        result.append(inp[i:j])
    result.append(inp[j:k])
    i=k
if i<len(inp):
    result.append(inp[k:])

print result
```

Here's what the output looks like.

```
['Ahh', 'wps ed', 'An']
```

This technique handles any non-matching prefix and suffix text as well. If you use an inp value of "prefixAhhwps edAnsuffix", you'll get the output I think you'd want:

```
['prefix', 'Ahh', 'wps ed', 'An', 'suffix']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re
import itertools
new_data = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([re.findall(".{"+str(len(i)/2)+"}", i) for i in inp.split()]))
```

Output:

```
['Ahh', 'wps', 'ed', 'An']
```